# Spring oauth2. Redirect to oauth/authorize AuthorizationEndpoint doesn't happen

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm implementing some kind of SSO system. I use Spring security oauth 2 in my applications. I have a client app (localhost:8081) an a server app (localhost:8080).

1. User tries to do a login from **Client App**. Client App in its turn starts authentication flow. It sends to **Server App** auth request http://localhost:8080/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client&scope=openid+email+address+profile+phone&redirect_uri=localhost:8081/login&nonce=3fc29332c5377&state=18960fbd838be
2. There is a redirect to login page and after entering credentials and submitting a form authentication is successful on server.
3. After that I'm expecting the flow continues authorization and go to oauth/authorize end point in org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint
   in irder to generate authorization code and send it back to Client App.
   But it doesn't.

Please help me to clarify why? Why after succesfull authentication the flow doesn't go to oauth/authorize end point.

This is my configuration for login andpoint:

```
<security:http pattern="/mylogin"
               create-session="stateless"
               entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/mylogin" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="customAuthenticationFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="authRequestFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" />
    <security:anonymous />
    <security:expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options policy="DENY" />
    </security:headers>
</security:http>
```

This is my custom auth filter:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationFilter.class);

public CustomAuthenticationFilter() {
    super("/mylogin");
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    if (!HttpMethod.POST.name().equals(request.getMethod())) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Authentication method not supported. Request method: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported");
    }
    String username = request.getParameter("j_username");
    String password = request.getParameter("j_password");
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(username) || StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Username or Password not provided");
    }
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    setDetails(request, authRequest);
    Authentication auth = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    return auth;
}

protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request,
                          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest) {
    authRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
}
```

}

There is my authorization-server config:

```
<oauth:authorization-server 
    client-details-service-ref="defaultOAuth2ClientDetailsEntityService"
    authorization-request-manager-ref="connectOAuth2RequestFactory" 
    token-services-ref="defaultOAuth2ProviderTokenService" 
    user-approval-handler-ref="tofuUserApprovalHandler" 
    request-validator-ref="oauthRequestValidator"
    redirect-resolver-ref="blacklistAwareRedirectResolver"
    authorization-endpoint-url="/authorize" 
    token-endpoint-url="/token"
    error-page="/error">

    <oauth:authorization-code authorization-code-services-ref="defaultOAuth2AuthorizationCodeService"/>
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password/>
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="chainedTokenGranter" />
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="jwtAssertionTokenGranter" />
    <oauth:custom-grant token-granter-ref="deviceTokenGranter" />

</oauth:authorization-server>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason.

**create-session="stateless"** is a reason why authentication has not been saved in security context.

That is why at the stage of processing authorization request (after successful authentication) there was an Access Denied exception in FilterSecurityInterceptor.